# Owin CookieAuthentication OnValidateIdentity doesn't call regenerateIdentityCallback

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I'm trying to use OnValidateIdentity to check for security stamp changes.
But somehow  when validateInterval runs out I got logged out and the validator doesn't call regenerateIdentityCallback here is the auth code from startup.cs

```
  app.CreatePerOwinContext(() =>
        {
            var uow = DependencyResolver.Current.GetService<IUnitOfWork>();
            return uow.UsersRepository.UserManager;
        });
        app.UseCookieAuthentication(new Microsoft.Owin.Security.Cookies.CookieAuthenticationOptions()
        {

            Provider = new CookieAuthenticationProvider()
            {
                OnApplyRedirect = context =>
                {
                    if (!context.Request.Path.StartsWithSegments(new PathString("/api")))
                        context.Response.Redirect(context.RedirectUri);
                },
                OnValidateIdentity = context => SecurityStampValidator.OnValidateIdentity<UserManager<User>, User, string>(
                    validateInterval: TimeSpan.FromSeconds(15),
                    regenerateIdentityCallback: (mngr, usr) =>
                    {
                        Debug.WriteLine("Regenerate identity");
                        var rolesStr = (mngr.GetRoles(usr.Id)).ToArray();
                        return AccountController.CreateClaims(usr, rolesStr);
                    },
                    getUserIdCallback: ci => 
                    {
                        return ci.GetUserId();
                    }).Invoke(context)
            },
            AuthenticationType = DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie,
            LoginPath = new PathString("/Account/"),
            CookieName = "Alisary",
            ExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(20),
            SlidingExpiration = false,
        });
```

UserManger is In the DAL layer. The code:

```
  public UserRepository(DatabaseContext context, IDataProtectionProvider dataProtection)
    {
        this.context = context;
        this.dataProtectionProvider = dataProtection;
        userManager = new UserManager<User>(
            new UserStore<User>(context));
        userManager.EmailService = new EmailSenderService();
        userManager.UserTokenProvider = new DataProtectorTokenProvider<User>(
            dataProtection.Create("protectionKey"))
        {
            TokenLifespan = TimeSpan.FromHours(24)
        };
        userManager.UserValidator = new UserValidator<User>(userManager)
        {
            AllowOnlyAlphanumericUserNames = false,
            RequireUniqueEmail = true
        };
        userManager.PasswordValidator = new PasswordValidator()
        {
            RequiredLength = 6,

        };


        roleManager = new RoleManager<IdentityRole>(
            new RoleStore<IdentityRole>(context));

    }
```

context is the database context.

Comment: Try with `OnValidateIdentity = context => SecurityStampValidator.OnValidateIdentity<ApplicationUserManager, DtbsUser, Guid>(
                            validateInterval: TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30),
                            regenerateIdentityCallback:
                                (manager, user) =>
                                    user.GenerateUserIdentityAsync(manager, context.Identity),
                            getUserIdCallback: (ci) => Guid.Parse(ci.GetUserId())).Invoke(context)`

Comment: I don't use ApplicationUserManager i use a custom one inside DAL layer. But when i changed String to Guid i got `the type UserManager<User> can't be used as type parameter TManger there is no implicit convertion from UserManager<User> to UserManger<User,Guid>` . i will also update my question with the code that generates my userManager.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I managed to solve my problem using a completely custom validation provider, instead of using SecurityStampValidator.

something similar to this code:

```
 Provider = new CookieAuthenticationProvider()
            {
                OnApplyRedirect = context =>
                {
                    if (!context.Request.Path.StartsWithSegments(new PathString("/api")))
                        context.Response.Redirect(context.RedirectUri);
                },
                OnValidateIdentity = async context =>
                {
                    var uow = DependencyResolver.Current.GetService<IUnitOfWork>();
                    var user = await uow.UsersRepository.FindUserByIdAsync(context.Identity.GetUserId());
                    uow.Reload(user);
                    var oldSecurityStamp = (context.Identity as ClaimsIdentity)
           .Claims.Where(x => x.Type.Equals(ClaimTypes.Expiration))
           .FirstOrDefault().Value;

                    if (!user.SecurityStamp.Equals(oldSecurityStamp))
                    {
                        context.RejectIdentity();
                        context.OwinContext.Authentication.SignOut(context.Options.AuthenticationType);
                    }
                }
                /*SecurityStampValidator.OnValidateIdentity<UserManager<User>, User, string>(
                    validateInterval: TimeSpan.FromSeconds(15),
                    regenerateIdentityCallback: (mngr, usr) =>
                    {
                        Debug.WriteLine("Regenerate identity");
                        var rolesStr = (mngr.GetRoles(usr.Id)).ToArray();
                        return AccountController.CreateClaims(usr, rolesStr);
                    },
                    getUserIdCallback: ci =>
                    {
                        return ci.GetUserId();
                    }).Invoke(context)*/
            },
            AuthenticationType = DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie,
            LoginPath = new PathString("/Account/"),
            CookieName = "Alisary",
            ExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(20),
            SlidingExpiration = true,
        });
```

the only problem about this code is that it check and hit the database on every authorized request which is fine to me now knowing that this won't hit by a normal people.

also i'm still open for suggestion if there is any solution to use SecurityStampValidator.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You are Invoking a new `SecurityStampValidator.OnValidateIdentity` on every call. To solve this create it before ...

```cs
var validator = SecurityStampValidator
    .OnValidateIdentity<ApplicationUserManager, ApplicationUser, Guid>(
        validateInterval: TimeSpan.FromSeconds(2),
        regenerateIdentityCallback: (manager, user) => user.GenerateUserIdentityAsync(manager),
        getUserIdCallback: (id) => id.GetUserGuid());

var cookieAuthenticationOptions = new CookieAuthenticationOptions
{
    Provider = new CookieAuthenticationProvider
    {
        // Not called on signin
        OnValidateIdentity = context =>
        {
             return validator.Invoke(context);
        }
    }
};
```

or do it without the context

```cs
var cookieAuthenticationOptions = new CookieAuthenticationOptions
{
    Provider = new CookieAuthenticationProvider
    {
        // Not called on signin
        OnValidateIdentity = validator,
    }
};
```